# Custom file parser slows down with every next file

Tags: c#, sql, parsing

I have built a simple file parser that reads a csv file line by line and adds it to the DB.

i dont commit changes to the DB till after the file is completely parsed.

It works fine but for some reason with every next file - the parsing becomes slower and slower
here is the code any suggestions on how to speed it up are very welcome.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CsvToSQL
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TransactionsEntities entities = new TransactionsEntities();

            string targetFolderPath = "C:\\Transactions\\";
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(targetFolderPath);

            //Loop through files in folder
            foreach (var file in allFiles)
            {
                //parse file
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(file))
                {
                    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                    int lineNo = 0;

                    while (!parser.EndOfData)
                    {

                        TransactionList transaction = new TransactionList();
                        //processing row
                        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                        try
                        {
                         if(lineNo % 20 == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(file + " Parsed line no: " + lineNo);
                            }   
                            transaction.Account = fields[0];
                            transaction.Timestamp = fields[1];
                            transaction.TransactionType = fields[2];
                            transaction.Status = fields[3];
                            transaction.Product = fields[4];
                            transaction.Price = fields[5];
                            transaction.BuySell = fields[6];
                            transaction.Series = fields[7];
                            transaction.Volume = fields[8];
                            transaction.FillVolume = fields[9];
                            transaction.OrderID = fields[10];
                            transaction.BestBid = fields[11];
                            transaction.BestAsk = fields[12];


                            entities.TransactionLists.Add(transaction);

                            lineNo++;



                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }

                    }
                    try
                    {
                        entities.SaveChanges();
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }



                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: suggest not add to entity in your loop, instead, add after all files are processed.

Comment: That would mean creating a list of "TransactionList" objects and then adding them to entity and saving it. Would this improve performance? Each file has around 30k rows and the firs 2 files fly through within minutes but then every next file becomes slower. Im not holding anything in memory so im wondering what is causing it to slow down?

Comment: not sure, but it would help find the bottle neck.

Comment: would you mind explaining how this will find the bottleneck? as creating 30k new variables seems even more excessive. Sorry im quite new to c#

Comment: I mean measure the performance of text file processing and database inserting separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all i found the memory issue with this - if anyone comes across a similar problem.

```html
 TransactionsEntities entities = new TransactionsEntities();
```

This is what is causing it to slow down so incredibly. It uses the same connection to DB replaced it with:

```html
 using (TransactionsEntities entities = new TransactionsEntities()){
 //Transaciton parsing code for 1 file
 }
```

and the application is flying through the files at 100x the speed it was before :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
TransactionsEntities entities = new TransactionsEntities();
```

Because Entity framework was not designed to work with bulk data in mind, it caches the entries in memory to minimize requeries etc. But adding lots of entries in a single context makes maintaining/checking cached data slow, which is your case.

You should better use SQLBulkCopy if you're using SQL server. It will add 100x more speed to your process.